# Custom Page in cPanel

Tags: hook, cpanel, custom-pages

It is possible to add coustom page to cPanle ?
Example:
cPanel url : https://127.0.0.1:2083 // cPanel default login Page
and I wanna create custom page like:
https://127.0.0.1:2083/mycustompage

Or if not how can I hook into default login page ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create your custom cPanel login page but you will have to edit your cPanel theme.

Please check following cPanel documentation.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Create+Custom-Branded+Login+Pages